# What are sources of accurate and interesting applied calculus problems for first-year students?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, education

I'm teaching applied or "business" calculus for the first time this semester. One of my goals is to make readily apparent the usefulness of calculus in most fields.

Our textbook has some such problems, but the citations are lacking. I'd really like to use recent data or models that I can cite directly. Does anyone know of a good database where I could find these things easily, or am I going to be coming up with my own student-friendly models for real data from a variety of sources?

An example of what I want: "A 2014 study by XXX proposed that the function
$$ f(x) = \; ... $$
is useful for estimating YYY. How many YYY will there be when...? When ..., how fast was the amount of YYY changing? [Source: a direct URL to XXX.]"

Comment: Though it is probably a bit much for 'business' calculus students, especially if they are new to calculus, but the [Black-Scholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black–Scholes_model#The_Black.E2.80.93Scholes_PDE) PDE is very useful for observing how option prices evolve over time.

Comment: One which is central to my line of business is the concept of duration.  Price sensitivity to interest rates.

Comment: Find the oldest calculus book you can. In my experience more-recent books tend to teach calculus in a very abstract way. This fine for students headed towards graduate work in mathematics, but not so good for students who want to relate calculus to the real world in the short term.